# Setting shadowImage On Translucent Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I am trying to set the shadowImage of the navigaion bar in my app delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-shadow"]];
```

This does not work by itself. It only works if I set the background image of the navigaion bar as well:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Here is my problem... the navigation bar is transluncent and I would like to keep it that way (no background images). But it seems that I cant set the shadowImage without setting the background image.

How can I set the shadowImage on translucent navigation bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot set a shadowImage of a navigationBar without setting its backgroundImage :

See UINavigationBar [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/shadowImage) :

> For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must
>   also be set with the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method.

But you can render shadowImage invisible with empty image :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc ]init]];
```

Comment: But this still doesn't work without a custom background image, which looses the translucency..? Is there a way to do it and keep the nice blurry effect?

Comment: I dont understand how this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

The response marked as an answer does not work if you want to keep the translucent effect in the NavigationBar.

A workaround I did was:

1) Create an Image with the color I wanted:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Then I assigned this as the `backgroundImage` to the `UINavigationBar`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Note that this makes the navigation bar fully transparent. Then I did the following to mimic the translucent 'blur' effect:

```
UIView *obfuscateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,64,self.view.frame.width)];
[obfuscateView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[obfuscateView setAlpha:0.9f];
[self.view addSubView:obfuscateView];
```

The main thing here is you need to now add an additional view behind the navigationBar that will mimic the blur effect. This can be achieved with a minimal hit to performance by playing with alpha transparency rather than actually doing the calculations using a blurring view. Also note that this `UIView` needs to be of the same color.

What this allows you to do though is also play with gradients that have varying alpha to create a fading effect into the nav bar.